# How to sort by presence of M2M (Pizza example)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Say I have the common pizza example:

```py
class Topping(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

With the following toppings:

```py
Topping.objects.create(order=1, name="tomato")
Topping.objects.create(order=2, name="cheese")
Topping.objects.create(order=3, name="olives")
Topping.objects.create(order=4, name="salami")
Topping.objects.create(order=5, name="onion")
Topping.objects.create(order=6, name="rocket")
```

Now say I had a pizza with `tomato`, `cheese` and `salami`.

I wish to get an order list of all the toppings of the pizza according to the `topping__order`, along with a list of all the toppings it does not have, also ordered by `topping__order`.

So it's sorted by first where the pizza has the topping, and secondly by the `topping__order` field.

The result would be something that has the same info as this (probably in a queryset though):

```py
{
    { "id": 1, "name": "tomato", "has_topping": True},
    { "id": 2, "name": "cheese", "has_topping": True},
    { "id": 3, "name": "salami", "has_topping": True},
    { "id": 2, "name": "olives", "has_topping": False},
    { "id": 5, "name": "onion" , "has_topping": False},
    { "id": 6, "name": "rocket", "has_topping": False},
}
```

Is this possible via a database query? (I can do it manually in Python via two queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [.order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) function:

```
Pizza.objects.all().order_by('id', 'toppings__order')
```

Comment: This will not order it by the presence of the M2M and then the `order` field.